# Why .NET Core (dnxcore50) xUnit Tests are not visible in VS2015 Test Explorer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I know this question is asked multiple times, but due to many changes in .NET Core, they become obsolete.

I have simple .NET Core library targeting Core (not Full .NET), now I want to configure Tests project for it.

Both projects compiles without problem, but I could not get tests to show up in *Test Explorer* in Visual Studio 2015.

Below are *project.json* files I managed to assemble from multiple documentation sources.

Do you see anything missing, perhaps some dependency?

===================

I am using :

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
- .NET Core 1.0.0 RC2

MyProject.dll

*project.json*

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

MyProject.Tests.dll

*project.json*

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-rc1-build204",
    "MyProject": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta4-build3444"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ".NET Core 1.0.0 RC2"? Are you serious? Now it should be 1.0.3 at least.

Comment: Thank's for pointing out, .NET Core is following JavaScript example - few month is entirety. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my particular case (At least i don't have issues launching tests from VS or console) xunit related dependencies look like this:

```
"dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
"xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
"xunit.extensibility.execution": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
"xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.2.0-beta2-build1149",
```

Don't pay attention to spesific versions. I believe **xunit.runner.visualstudio** package is what you need here

Comment: Try to add  **"testRunner": "xunit" ** to your project.json file. There is a universal approach as well,  just run **dotnet new -t xunittest** to create brand new xunit project which is being detected in VS for sure and compare the project.json with yours.